# localtimestamp or curent_timestamp for default value

Tags: oracle, timestamp

In Oracle-12c I have some columns that I am converting from timestamp with time zone to timestamp with local time zone. Some of those same columns also currently have a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Should I change the default values to use the LOCALTIMESTAMP function instead? The columns seem to populate fine if I just leave the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default values. Is there any practical reasons or gotchas for using one over the other in this case. I have been combing the docs but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You write "I don't need the time zone information", however datatype `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` has time zone information stored.

For a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column I don't see any difference between `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `LOCALTIMESTAMP` either of them should work in the same way.

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns current data and time as of datatype `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, whereas `LOCALTIMESTAMP` returns a `LOCALTIMESTAMP` value. Both of them have to be implicitly converted to a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` datatype.